# How to aggregate filtered listapiview queryset and return value once

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

**How to perform aggregations on filtered querysets and return the value only once?**

My existing code below. In the serializer, of course PZ.objects.all() makes it aggregate all items. I don't know how to get the queryset from the serializer level. To make the total value appear once, it would be a good idea to add a field in the view. However, overriding def list(): makes the filtering stop working.

I need this because I am working on a table that shows documents with filtering capabilities. In addition, there will be pagination. After selecting, for example, a creation date range, the values of the documents must be summed.

View:

```
class PZListAPIView(ListAPIView):
    queryset = PZ.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PZModelSerializer
    filterset_fields = {
        'id': ['exact', 'in', 'contains', 'range']
    }
```

Serializer:

```
class PZModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    net_value_sum = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_net_value_sum')
    class Meta:
        model = PZ
        fields = '__all__'
    
    def get_net_value_sum(self, obj):
        return PZ.objects.aggregate(Sum('net_value'))['net_value__sum']
```

Response:

```
[
    {
        "id": 41,
        "net_value_sum": 28.0,
        "status": "C",
        "net_value": "6.00"
    },
    {
        "id": 42,
        "net_value_sum": 28.0,
        "status": "S",
        "net_value": "10.00"
    }
]
```

Desired response:

```
[
    "net_value_sum": 16.0,
    {
        "id": 41,
        "status": "C",
        "net_value": "6.00"
    },
    {
        "id": 42,
        "status": "S",
        "net_value": "10.00"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a solution to this problem myself. You need to override the 'def list():' method while returning the filtered queryset. Then on this queryset in the view we return with the aggregated value. The code looks like this:

```
class PZListAPIView(ListAPIView):
    queryset = PZ.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PZModelSerializer
    filterset_fields = {
        'id': ['exact', 'in', 'contains', 'range']
    }
    
    def get_queryset(self):
        return PZ.objects.all()

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())

        page = self.paginate_queryset(queryset)
        if page is not None:
            serializer = self.get_serializer(page, many=True)
            return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)

        serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)
        
        net_value = queryset.aggregate(Sum('net_value'))['net_value__sum']
        return Response([{'net_value': net_value},serializer.data])
```

Comment: what about pagination?